# Python multicore programming

Tags: python, multicore, multiprocess

Please consider a class as follow:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def do_task(self):
        #do something with data
```

In my application I've a list containing several instances of Foo class. The aim is to execute `do_task` for all Foo objects. A first implementation is simply:

```
 #execute tasks of all Foo Object instantiated
 for f_obj in my_foo_obj_list:
     f_obj.do_task()
```

I'd like to take advantage of multi-core architecture sharing the `for` cycle between 4 CPUs of my machine.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: You can use multiprocessing module.

 https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1182350/1982962) it will help you

Answer (score 22):

You can use [process pools](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) in multiprocessing module.

```
def work(foo):
    foo.do_task()

from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool()
pool.map(work, my_foo_obj_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: +1 This is a very nice and fast to implement.

Comment: how do I wait so all processes would finish?

Comment: @FlashThunder When `pool.join()` returns all processes finished.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of going through all the multithreading/multicore basics, I would like to reference a Post by Ryan W. Smith: [Multi-Core and Distributed Programming in Python](http://www.praetorian.com/blog/multi-core-and-distributed-programming-in-python)

He will go into details how you can utilize multiple cores and use those concepts. But please be careful with that stuff if you are not familiar with general multithreading concepts.

[Functional Programming](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html) will also allow you to customize the algorithm/function for each core.