# Python - How to make use of multiple CPU cores

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, operating-system, python-2.x

I know that Python programs execute as a single process using a single CPU.

Does this mean that opening 4 command prompts and launching, one after the other, 4 different .py scripts will result in making use of 4 CPU cores?

My system:

- Alienware Workstation - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20 GHz
- Windows 10 Home Edition
- Python 2.7.15

Comment: You should take a look at [python multiprocessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537037/python-multicore-programming)

Comment: yes.  those are separate processes and under windows (and most OSs) they will normally be scheduled to run in parallel on multiple cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you're right: you'll use one CPU core with one `python` process. However, there are many ways which allow you to use more than one CPU core. Have a look at the official Python docs about [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

This is an example, which will stress your CPU on all its cores:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def random_calculation(x):
    while True:
        x * x

p = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
p.map(random_calculation, range(cpu_count()))
```