# Asyncio Threading

Tags: python, asynchronous

How do I make my code perform in a much faster fashion? How would I go about threading with async? This goes faster than just running like usual; however, it is not really up to my needs. I've heard people say that Async can go to 500 threads efficiently, but I haven't seen any docs about it...

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Using multiple threads is *not faster* since it still uses a single core. You are probably thinking of [multicore processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182315/python-multicore-processing) if you want to speed up your computations.

Comment: Still cannot find any info about doing a threadpool with multiprocessing.